# Render folium map other than by asking for object representation

Tags: python, folium

The only way that I've found you can render a folium map is by simply asking for object representation:

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])

m
```

But what if you wanted to display the map from a function?  I've tried something like the following on Jupyter but it doesn't produce anything:

```
def render(m):
   m
```

Is there a method for this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out display(m) does the trick.